# calculating length

Tags: geometry

There are two round objects that have a 50 cm diameter and are 2 cm away from eachother that have a belt around them both how long is the belt?

Could somebody explain me how to solve this, please?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram. What will be the shape of this belt ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sketch. If you need help with this, please ask. A sketch shows how you are viewing the problem. Please edit rather than ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Make a sketch! In total you have two half circles and two line segments of length distance plus twice the radius.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this sketch will help you solve the problem.

You will need to identify which portion of the diagram contributes to the total length of the belt. You will also need to know how to calculate the circumference of a circle.

How much of each circle is covered by a belt? How much more belt length is needed to encompass both circles?

(Apologies for the roughness of the diagram and the white space. I downloaded a phone app just for this. ;) )

[image: Circles and belts]